# A new tag for the machine learning toolkit called Bob

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

There is a signal processing and machine learning toolkit called [Bob](https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/) which was [first released in 2012](https://pypi.org/project/bob/#history) and has been active since then. Sometimes the users of this toolkit ask questions about it on Stack Overflow. However since the name is generic (`Bob`), it's very hard to filter and find questions on Bob.

I was wondering if someone with enough privileges in the community can create a tag for Bob so that its questions can easily be found. My suggestion is [bob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bob) or [python-bob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-bob). Please keep in mind that Bob not only offers a Python API but also offers a C++ API and it [can be used in C++](https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.example.cmake).

Here are some questions on Bob which I could find:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810797/error-while-installing-bob-via-pip-on-ubuntu?s=1|21.5535](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810797/error-while-installing-bob-via-pip-on-ubuntu?s=1%7C21.5535)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579280/cannot-install-bob-measure-python-package/37590990?s=2|17.1648#37590990](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579280/cannot-install-bob-measure-python-package/37590990?s=2%7C17.1648#37590990)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173799/importerror-with-bob-core-oserror-bob-core-libbob-core-so-undefined-symbol/43230429?s=3|15.4519#43230429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173799/importerror-with-bob-core-oserror-bob-core-libbob-core-so-undefined-symbol/43230429?s=3%7C15.4519#43230429)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694772/how-to-install-bob-on-python3?s=5|11.9918](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694772/how-to-install-bob-on-python3?s=5%7C11.9918)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663397/cant-install-bob-package-by-pip?s=6|9.0922](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663397/cant-install-bob-package-by-pip?s=6%7C9.0922)

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of Bob. I can also promote the tag on Bob's website as well if it is created.

Comment: Since `bob` is pretty generic, and `python-bob` would appear to exclude the C++ API, how about something like `bob-machine-learning`? Just a thought.

Comment: How about [bob-api]

Comment: You have a duplicate in your list. Also most of those questions dont really seem recent (2016 and 2017). So why are you asking this now? (Not against it, just sceptic)

Comment: I think `python-bob` is good enough since it is mostly used within python and high level packages are written in Python only. We didn't know people ask about bob on stackoverflow. We have a mailing list. However, I imagine if there is a tag here, we could also point questions to stackoverflow.

Comment: I just created the tag python-bob following this discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [python-bob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-bob) tag was created. Thank you.